# Имитирование устройства RS-232 в Linux

Tags: rs232

Моя задача: написать обработчик кнопок пульта, который в будущем будет подсоединен к компьютеру по RS-232. Самого пульта и других устройств, с помощью которых можно отладить программу, написанную на C++ (используя QSerialPort), пока не имеется.

Вопрос состоит в следующем: имеется ли какое-нибудь специальное ПО под Linux, которое имитирует устройства по RS-232?

Моя программа будет принимать сигналы с устройства по RS-232 и выводить их в консоль (выводить какая кнопка нажата)

Comment: ответ зависит от того, чего ожидает ваша программа и что именно вы подразумеваете под «имитированием». т.е., во-первых, вопрос не ясен, во-вторых, слишком глобален. попробуйте его как-то конкретизировать, нажав [edit].

Comment: Можете сами сделать аппаратно-программный эмулятор. Сделайте заглушку с перемычкой rx-tx (2-3 на разъёме DB-9), и посылайте команды, которые должен отправлять пульт

Comment: alexander barakin, конкретизировал